# What is the correct IE browser and document mode for the Sitecore 7.1 UI (shell site)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

What is the correct IE browser and document mode for the Sitecore 7.1 shell ?

Sitecore 7.0 IE10 Compat View / doc mode: IE5 quirks

**Sitecore 7.1 IE10 / doc mode: Standards (?)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Release Notes](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx), Sitecore should now support IE in standard rendering mode:

> All supported browsers now render the Sitecore Desktop and other
>   Sitecore clients using "standards" mode. Previously, the Sitecore
>   clients were rendered using "quirks mode" in Internet Explorer.
>   (389935, 392576)

If that doesn't work for you, contact support to report it as a bug.

Comment: If you use Standards mode you'll find that tabs are buggy, this has been reported to SC support.

Answer (score 0):

IE 10 browser in Quirks document mode works fine for me.